# Sinon Spy is not called if the spied method is called indirectly

Tags: javascript, sinon

### Problem

In our codebase we have a problem with sinon which can be reproduced with the code snipped below. The thing is that it seems to be that indirect called spies return force `false`, the `console.log` clearly states that the method is called but the `spy.called` remains `false`.

### Code

The following CDN's can be used for the html:

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sinon.js/1.7.3/sinon-min.js
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.1.14/require.min.js
```

main.js

```
require(['myModule'], function(module) {

    //using sinon
    var methodCallerSpy = sinon.spy(module, 'methodCaller')
    console.log(methodCallerSpy); // methodCaller
    module.methodCaller();
    console.log(methodCallerSpy.called); //true


    var methodSpy = sinon.spy(module, 'method');
    console.log(methodSpy); //method
    module.methodCaller();
    console.log(methodSpy.called); // false
    module.method();
    console.log(methodSpy.called); // true

});
```

And the module

```
define(function() {
    const method = () => console.log('method called by methodCaller');

    const methodCaller = () => method();

    return{
        method,
        methodCaller
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that `myModule` has two private functions called `method()` and `methodCaller()` as well as two methods it exposes with the same names.

Sinon is capable on spying on the exposed methods, but not the internal functions.

When you call `module.method()` your invoking the exposed method, so Sinon is able to detect the call. However, when you call `method.methodCaller()`, `methodCaller()` calls the `method()` private function directly, and therefore the call is not detected by Sinon.

If you change your `methodCaller()` function to:

```
methodCaller = function(){
    this.method();
}
```

... then Sinon should be able to capture the "indirect" call to `method()` when calling `methodCaller()`.

Comment: Is there a solution for this exact proble, I don't want to call the methods of a module like this.method just to be able to spy on them ...

Comment: Unfortunately no.